# Converting from Integer value to StringBuffer with zeros as the default value

Tags: java, arrays, integer, stringbuffer

I am trying to form a StringBuffer with an initial value of 00000..

My problem is the initial value is dependent on an integer variable and based on the value of integer variable that many number of zeros should be there in StringBuffer..

E.g. int length=9, therefore my StringBuffer should form with 000000000....(9 zeros)...

I am not getting a way out of this problem. Can anyone please guide me on this.

One way I figured out is by getting the integer value and storing that many values in String array and then writing string array to StringBuffer but seems to be very inefficient method. Please guide me.

Comment: One way is to run a loop with an index as the value of integer variable and append 0 in every loop to stringBuffer....Any other way out of this problem...???

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#format(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...)

Answer (score 1):

```
int numZeroes = 5;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < numZeroes; i++)
{
    sb.append('0');
}
```

Comment: Appending a char '0' would be more efficient than a string "0".

Comment: True enough. It's late, and I should probably be in bed :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a utility method you could use:

```
public StringBuilder repeatChars(StringBuilder sb, char c, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        sb.append(c);
    }

    return sb;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

// Add nine zeroes
repeatChars(sb, '0', 9);
```

Note: I made it return the `StringBuilder` so that you can chain method calls.

It's better to use `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`, because `StringBuilder` doesn't have the unnecessary synchronization that `StringBuffer` has.

There's really no other, more efficient way than to do this with a loop. Don't worry too much about micro-optimization (worrying that simple statements are not efficient enough).

Comment: Well i commented on my question seconds after my post mentioning the same logic....Thanks for the help...!....

Comment: Missing out on an excellent opportunity to use the "goes to" operator, `while(n --> 0)` :-D

Comment: @glowcoder the "goes to" operator? Are you serious? That doesn't exist in Java.

Comment: @Jesper it's a joke, but it is actually valid Java. It's actually a combination of the `--` operator and the `>` operator.

Comment: @glowcoder Aha, it would indeed even work, interesting trick! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're stuck with Java 1.4.2 (or earlier) or you have a *very specific* reason to use `StringBuffer`, you should almost always use a [`StringBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead.

What's wrong with a trivial loop:

```
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(length); // might want to use more if you know that you'll append something
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  buf.append('0');
}
```

And if you know the maximum number of zeroes to use, then you might do this:

```
// make sure never to change the content of this
private static final char[] ZEROES = new char[] { '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0' };

// when you need the zeroes do this:
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(length);
buf.append(ZEROES, 0, length);
```

Comment: well i know the number of zeros which is dependent on integer variable but I certainly dont want to use any array........i figured it out./..It can easily be done using a loop....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's anything to do it in a single line, but you can use:

```
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(length);
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    buffer.append('0');
}
```

(I *suspect* appending a `char` is marginally more efficient than appending a string, as there's no need for a nullity check and the length is known. It won't be significant though.)

If you're using Java 5 or higher, it's generally better to use `StringBuilder` than `StringBuffer`, by the way, so that you don't have unnecessary synchronization.

This uses the length as the initial capacity, which is good if you aren't going to append any more - but if you're going to append data afterwards, change it appropriately to give a larger capacity.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer and possibly not useful, but *if* you are using Apache Commons Lang, and many significant Java projects do, you have what you want with their `StrBuilder`, particularly with its [appendPadding](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/text/StrBuilder.html#appendPadding%28int,%20char%29) method.

You can write:

```
StrBuilder b = new StrBuilder();
b.appendPadding(9, '0').append(...).append(...)....
```